# In the movie I, Robot why is Lanning's house scheduled for demolition?

Tags: i-robot-2004

Wouldn't Lanning's house be turned into a museum, considering his importance, rather than be demolished?

Comment: @Thaddeus - aggreed.  I searched for Lanning, but that question is a ways down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To hide the trail of the USR artificial intelligence.